# Using XML XSLT, how to update a particular data inside an XML?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Consider the below example. I have to change the value of an attribute inside setData

```
<system>
    <Groups>
        <Group id="01" check="true">
            <name>Value</name>
            <age>test</age>
            <setData>
                <data type="module">module</data>
                <data enabled="true">true</data>
            </setData>
        </Group>
        <Group id="02" check="true">
            <name>Value</name>
            <age>test</age>
            <setData>
                <data type="module">module</data>
                <data enabled="true">true</data>
            </setData>
        </Group>
    </Groups>
</system>
```

I have to update 'enabled' attribute value to "false" in Group with id="01"

So the expected output is

```
<Group id="01" check="true">
    <name>Value</name>
    <age>test</age>
    <setData>
        <data type="module">module</data>
        <data enabled="false">false</data>
    </setData>
</Group>
```

Below given is the XL style sheet I have used. Can some one help on this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />    
<xsl:param name="groupId" />
<xsl:param name="isEnabledStatus" />

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="setData" >
    <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
  <xsl:if test="@data = enabled">
    <plan id="{$groupId}">
     <xsl:attribute name="enabled"><xsl:value-of select="$isEnabledStatus"/></xsl:attribute> 
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So you write 'I have to update 'enabled' attribute value to "false" in Group with id="01"' but then you show us an expected output of `<data enabled="true">true</data>`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. Changed same on the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

For your verbal description I would simply use

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Group[@id = '01']/setData/data[@enabled = 'true']">
      <data enabled="false">false</data>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqi

If you also need the parameters shown you will need to explain what you need them for and which values you want to set them to.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. 
"isEnabledStatus"  will hold the true/false to be set. How to get the value from "isEnabledStatus" and place instead of hard coded values.

Comment: Do you need to toggle the value, i.e. if  `@enabled = 'true'` you need to set it to `false` and if `@enabled = 'false'` you need to set it to `true`? Can it also occur that you want to run the stylesheet without setting the parameter and basically ignore it?

Comment: No I just wanted to place the parameter value there. What ever value is contained in parameter, it should get placed in those positions.

Comment: Do you need the parameter both to compare and to set the value? Setting is easy with a global `<xsl:param name="isEnabledStatus"/>` and then instead of `<data enabled="false">false</data>` you use `<data enabled="{$isEnabledStatus}"><xsl:value-of select="$isEnabledStatus"/></data>`.  The only problem with XSLT 1 is using a parameter or variable reference in a match pattern (i.e. where I hard coded the comparison `@enabled = 'true'`).